The set of vectors with rationally independent coordinates is dense?
My question is somehow related to this previous question by Meemo, in which he asked for a orthogonal set of four vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with rationally independent coordinates. I would like to have a related result for $\mathbb{R}^n$:
We say $a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ are rationally independent (or linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$) if for any $q_1, q_2, \dotsc, q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfying
$$
a_1q_1 + a_2q_2 + \dotsc + a_nq_n = 0
$$
implies that $q_1 = q_2 = \dots = q_n = 0$.
Now let $A := \{(v_1, v_2, \dotsc, v_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : v_1, v_2, \dotsc, v_n \text{ are rationally independent}\}$ be the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with rationally independent coordinates.
It seems to me that this set should be dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but cannot seem to prove it.
Thank you in advance!

The simplest proof I have in mind requires two tools:

induction over $n$
the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is countable, while every interval of $\mathbb R$ is uncountable.

I use this notation for $k=1, \dots , n$: the interval $I_k = (a_k ; b_k)$ is any bounded interval in $\Bbb R$. Consider the product of intervals
$$I_1 \times \cdots \times I_n$$
it is enough to prove that there exist an element $(v_1; \dots ; v_n) \in A \cap (I_1 \times \cdots \times I_n)$
The base step of induction is the case $n=1$, which is obvious.
For the inductive step, we know that $A \cap (I_1 \times \cdots \times I_{n-1})$ is not empty. Pick any element $$(v_1; \dots ; v_{n-1}) \in A \cap (I_1 \times \cdots \times I_{n-1})$$ The set of rational linear combinations of $v_1, \dots , v_{n-1}$ is
$$V= \mathrm{span}_{\Bbb Q} (v_1, \dots , v_{n-1})$$
$V$ is a countable subset of $\Bbb R$, so in particular there exists
$$v_n \in I_{n} \setminus V$$
By construction $v_1, \dots , v_n$ are rationally independent and $v_k \in I_k$. This concludes the proof.

Even if you fix $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ rationally independent, the set of vectors $v = (v_1, \dots, v_n)$ with $v_i \in \mathbb{Q} a_i$ is already dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, its image $\mathbb{Q} a_i$ under the homeomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}; x \mapsto xa_i$ is dense. Now the product $\mathbb{Q}a_1 \times \dots \times \mathbb{Q}a_n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is dense since any non-empty open set contains some basic open set of the form $U_1 \times \dots \times U_n$ with each $U_i$ non-empty open and therefore containing some $v_i \in \mathbb{Q}a_i$.
